# CDF of first passage time for Poisson dam/shot noise with constant amplitude jumps and exponential decay

Tags: poisson-distribution, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I'm looking for a CDF (either exact or approximation) of the first passage time, $T$, of a storage process $\{X(t); 0 \leq t < \infty \},$ with constant (unit) input jumps occurring in a Poisson process with mean rate of $\lambda$ jumps per unit time, an exponential decay rate, alpha $X(t)$, and initial value $X(0) = x_0$.

I found several references in the literature of similar problems where the inputs are compound Poisson, i.e. both the intervals between successive inputs and the input *amplitudes* are exponentially distributed, e.g.:

- Harrison, J.M & Resnick, S (1976) The stationary distribution and
  first exit probabilites of a storage process with general release
  rate.  Mathematics of Operations Res. 1, 347-358.
- Yeo, G.F. (2010) Rediscoveries of a first passage time result for
  dams and shot noise.  Mathematical Scientist vol. 35, no. 1, 18-22

as well as an example of input and release amplitudes both constant:

- Moran, P.A.P. (1959) The Theory of Storage 79-81.

But I haven't been able to find the case of constant amplitude inputs and exponential decay.

Comment: This looks quite similar to some of the processes considered in recent credit-risk research. They tend to consider processes that, I believe, are a bit more complicated. There was a student at Cornell (where S. Resnick also resides) named Kay Giesecke that wrote about such things. That might be a place to start. Darrell Duffie may also look at similar processes, though I haven't followed his work very closely.

Comment: This problem is also of interest in neuroscience. E.g. similar problems were considered in:
R. M. Capocelli, L. M. Ricciardi.
Diffusion approximation and first passage time problem for a model neuron. June 1971, Volume 8, Issue 6, pp 214-223